# Android SQLite: table user has no column named

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here's part of my SQLiteHandler class code.

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DataKeyLists {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // query to create a login table
    private static final String QUERY_CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER
            + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BIRTHDAY + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_RELIGION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_NATIONALITY + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT"
            + KEY_UPDATED_AT + " TEXT"
            + ")";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUserIntoSQLite(String uid, String name, String status, String email, String gender, String birthday, String created_at, String updated_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid);
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        values.put(KEY_STATUS, status);
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, gender);
        values.put(KEY_BIRTHDAY, birthday);
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at);
        values.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT, updated_at);

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "New user is added into sqlite: " + id);
    }
}
```

I later added a new column `KEY_UPDATED_AT` the `QUERY_CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE` query and restarted the application.
Now I get the following message on the Logcat.

```
Error inserting uid=564ef4c43388d0.82002082 birthday=1982-07-27 updated_at=null email=learn@android.com status=user name=learnandroid created_at=2015-11-20 05:24:04 gender=Male
11-20 15:41:42.976 8659-8852/? E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named updated_at (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO user(uid,birthday,updated_at,email,status,name,created_at,gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

It seems like the table is dropped and newly created if there is a version difference.
I think the `onUpgrade()` takes that part, but why am I still getting that error message?

I also uninstalled the app on my device, cleaned and rebuilt the project on Android Studio and re-ran the application.
This didn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

You miss a comma here:

```
+ KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT"
+ KEY_UPDATED_AT + " TEXT"
```

It has to be

```
+ KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT, "
+ KEY_UPDATED_AT + " TEXT"
```

Then uninstall and reinstall your app (in order for the database to be recreated).
Or simply increase the DATABASE_VERSION constant value (i.e.: set it to 3).

Comment: Oh my! It was really a little flaw on the query. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @MD It happens, my dear... ;)

Comment: eagle eyes @Frank N, Stein

Comment: @newbieprogrammer To be "picky", this is not a `query`, byt a SQL `command` (a DDL command, to be more precise). ;)

Comment: @coeus just habit... it's a frequent question ;)